# Can somebody please explain this SQL LEFT JOIN behavior to get previous value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to understand why a query behaves the way it does. I have a table with customers, revenue, sales year, and sale semester. I want to find the previous year revenue by self-joining to the table. I am well versed in using LAG and I am not looking an alternative solution, just somebody who can explain why the following works, explicitly. Here is a temp table, one customer account to keep it simple. The join is a self LEFT JOIN on customer, year, and semester. In the join it's c.SaleYear = p.SaleYear + 1. That plus 1 allows the previous record to be returned and it's just not intuitive when looking at it. If somebody could please explain how this works:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sales (
     CustomerNumber int
    ,SaleYear int
    ,SaleSemester int
    ,Revenue decimal(7,2) );

INSERT INTO #Sales
SELECT 123, 2012, 1, 18.00;
INSERT INTO #Sales
SELECT 123, 2012, 1, 19.00;
INSERT INTO #Sales
SELECT 123, 2014, 3, 13.00;
INSERT INTO #Sales
SELECT 123, 2015, 2, 31.00;
INSERT INTO #Sales
SELECT 123, 2015, 3, 27.00;
INSERT INTO #Sales
SELECT 123, 2016, 2, 92.00;
INSERT INTO #Sales
SELECT 123, 2017, 3, 10.00;

-- Begin query

SELECT 
     c.CustomerNumber
    ,c.SaleYear
    ,c.SaleSemester
    ,c.Revenue AS Revenue
    ,ISNULL(p.Revenue, 0) AS PreviousRevenue
    ,p.SaleYear AS PreviousYear
    ,p.SaleSemester AS PreviousSemester
FROM #Sales c
LEFT JOIN #Sales p ON c.CustomerNumber = p.CustomerNumber AND c.SaleYear = p.SaleYear + 1 AND c.SaleSemester = p.SaleSemester
```

Comment: As a point, the results not true, while `2016` take the first `2015` instead the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply matching records where p.SaleYear is one LESS than c.SaleYear. That is, if p.SaleYear is 2016 and c.SaleYear is 2017, then p.SaleYear + 1 = c.SaleYear. So, you're finding the prior year's records by adding one to their year rather than subtracting one from the current year's record.

Or maybe you could think of it this way. Each condition in the where clause is essentially a pair of expressions that it is comparing:

(expression 1) = (expression 2)

If the result of that comparison is true, then it is considered a match. So in your query you have

(c.SaleYear) = (p.SaleYear + 1)

Both expressions are evaluated, and a match is found when both sides of the comparison evaluate to the same value. Or to use my previous example:

(2017) = (2016 + 1)

Comment: And where `c.SaleSemester = p.SaleSemester` too, which won't work if `SaleSemester` are diffrent.

Comment: Yes, and if CustomerNumber is the same as well. I was just trying to focus on why it finds the prior year's record which is all tied up in that part of the where clause.

Comment: Thanks, Lyle. That was well explained. At first glance, it doesn't seem intuitive to me. It does make more sense to me now.